Galaxy A14G - Camera video feedback different than captured photo
I'm working on a web app that uses WebRTC to capture video from a cellphone camera. I've noticed a color accuracy issue on A14G devices. In low-light conditions, the camera's video preview appears significantly duller than the actual captured images. For instance, a photo with four distinct green, blue, red, and light pink dots shows vibrant colors, while the video feed portrays them as muted, especially the light pink which appears completely gray.
This problem persists with automatic settings enabled. However, manually adjusting the ISO improves the video preview. I've tested other phones with identical settings (ISO, shutter, white balance, etc.), but only the A14G exhibits this color inaccuracy. Has anyone else experienced this issue, and if so, how did you resolve it? 
